# Is grub2 the 1.99 version of grub?

Tags: grub2

As the title. Sorry for the confusing question.

The reason why I ask this, is that when you update systemd, there are two ways of setting up the grub list, one is for grub classic, one is for grub2.

I am not sure the digit 2 in grub2 is a version number or the software name is called grub2.

If grub version 1.99 is not grub2 but grub, how can you update to grub2 (under ubuntu 12.04)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GRUB 2 is version 1.98 or later.

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)

Answer (score 0):

Both are updated the same way:

```
sudo update-grub
```